# Are there any important treasure chests at Nevermore?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I'm playing Ni No Kuni and I finished the Miasma Marshes, entered Nevermore, defeated Shadar and now I'm almost at the end of the game (doing the Ash Clouds "missions").  My travel through Nevermore was very fast and I missed lots of its treasures, as I was only exploring, but I defeated Shadar and I decided to continue the game.

My question is: Is there a problem with skipping the chests in Nevermore? Are there any important treasures that I won't find anyplace else (i.e. that I would only find in Nervermore)? Will this compromise any trophy achievement? I have a save before entering Nervermore, so if those chests are important I can go back and redo these parts, but if there is no problem, I will continue the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no missable trophies in this game, which is good because it would take an age to reply the game just for a trophy.

[Here is my source](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/ni-no-kuni-wrath-white-witch/173081-ni-no-kuni-wrath-white-witch-trophy-guide-roadmap-jp.html)

I cannot say if there are any unique items at that point. There are no trophies that require you to collect all items. There is one for all hidden treasures, but they are the ones hidden on the world map, which you can still access post-game.

I think it is safe to not worry about it and continue to play... although I am sure 2 months down the line you have already made the decision ;-)

EDIT: You have a chance to revisit Nevermore post-game.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your explanation, but I already stoped to play Ni No Kuni. I don't have patience enough to catch all trophies ;)